# jQuery - Adding HTML to specific table column ID?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a column named id"tblCol1".  How can I use jQuery to add HTML a href tags aroudn the content of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Which row/column intersection, (td), do you want to wrap in an anchor within this "column"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the wrap() function.

```
$mycol.wrap(jQuery('a').attr('href','http://somwhere.com'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume your table has a `<thead>` with one of the `<th>`s having that ID.

If that's the case, you would do:

```
// Get column index
var col = $("#tblCol1").index();

// Wrap each table cell with that index
$("table tbody tr").find("td:eq(" + col + ")").each(function () {
    $(this).html("<a>" + $(this).html() + "</a>");
});
```

If not, and you mean that each row has a `<td>` with that ID, then... you shouldn't you duplicate IDs. Change them to classes instead, and  use:

```
$("table td.tblCol1").each(function () {
    $(this).html("<a>" + $(this).html() + "</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `html()` method can set and return the HTML that is in an element.

```
$('tblCol1').html("<a>" + $('tblCol1').html() + "</a>");
```

If there is no HTML (just text) in the cell, you can use:

```
$('tblCol1').html("<a>" + $('tblCol1').text() + "</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Point of clarification regarding ids for columns.

To give an id to an entire column you have to use the `<colgroup>` tag plus, optionally, the `<col>` tag; you can't do it with the `<thead>` tag as suggested above.

For example, if you want to give an id to the first column in a table, you could code something like this (`<colgroup>` must come immediately after the `<table>` tag):

```
<colgroup span="1" id="column1"></colgroup>
```

To assign an id encompassing the first 3 columns in a table, it would look like this:

```
<colgroup span="3" id="columngroup1"></colgroup>
```

To assign each column in a table an id, then you have to use `<col>` tags, like so:

```
<colgroup>
  <col id="col1" />
  <col id="col2" />
</colgroup>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp for details